# Java: Finding the cause of OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, maven, out-of-memory, bash

I'm trying to build a Java app in my Terminal (I'm using Eclipse, but Terminal just to see if it works), and I keep getting stuck at this message:

```
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread     "main"
```

It was recommended that I add this line of code to my .profile (I have a .bash_profile, but not a .profile), so I did:

```
MAVEN_OPTS="-XX:MaxPermSize=512m"
```

But I'm still getting the error. Here's what my .bash_profile file looks like:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
source ~/.bashrc
fi

MAVEN_OPTS="-XX:MaxPermSize=512m"

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin

##
# Your previous /Users/tom.maxwell/.bash_profile file was backed up as   /Users/tom.maxwell/.bash_profile.macports-saved_2013-03-04_at_15:51:37
##

# MacPorts Installer addition on 2013-03-04_at_15:51:37: adding an appropriate PATH        variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.


##
@                                                                               
".bash_profile" 46L, 1730C
```

What should I do? The app I'm trying to run is quite large, and I'm not familiar with Java (I'm mostly a JS/CSS person).

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to be in the script, the OOME occurs because of some problem in the Java code. Please post the relevant parts here.

Comment: `MAVEN_OPTS` is only for using maven to build your code. Are you using maven to run your code too? How are you running your code? Specifically, what is the command you are using which causes this error? If you are using `java` directly to run the JAR file, try using the parameters `-Xms` and `-Xmx` instead.

Comment: @Jesse - yes, I'm using Maven. The command I use is "mvn tomcat7:run"

Comment: @TomMaxwell Then try this: `MAVEN_OPTS='-Xms256m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m'`

Comment: Just remember that changes to your `.bash_profile` file won't be used right away. I think you have to restart your terminal, or maybe even log out and then log back in. Or, just run `. ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: `mvn tomcat7:run` doesn't build anything, it runs tomcat 7 server. so are you actually building anything or not? and at which point are you getting the message?

Comment: Fixed it. After I fixed the MAVEN_OPTS problem I was getting an error finding Java. Turns out I had multiple tomcat servers going and when I changed the Java string in my .profile they couldn't find it.

Answer (score 2):

you're changing the permgen size which holds classes and stuff.

instead you want to change maximum memory, adding
`MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms512M -Xmx2048M"`

should fix your problem.

Comment: To the MAVEN_OPTS or vm options? Could you tell me where I can add that to the vm options? I'm new to this... Just trying to get this app building so I can do front-end work and testing.

Comment: try adding it to maven_opts

Answer (score 1):

Add this parameter as argument in your server params

-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xms512m

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and I was facing the similar issue. The thing that worked for me is adding this line to .bashrc

```
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx756m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m"
```

After that just restart your system.